# Shall I kill my desktop app converter process?

Tags: wpf, uwp, installation, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I am converting my desktop wpf app into uwp, and I am using the desktop app converter, I follow the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) and all works fine, until I run below command:

DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer "C:\Users\My Name\Desktop\publish installer\setup.exe" -InstallerArguments "/S" -Destination "C:\Result" -PackageName "MyTestApplication" -Publisher "CN=MyTestApplication" -Version 0.0.0.1 -MakeAppx -Verbose

In my desktop app converter screen it shows:
Running Installer in Isolated Environment

VERBOSE: No installer valid exit codes specified. Using defaults: 0
VERBOSE: Replace any occurence of  in -InstallerArguments with C:\shared\logs
VERBOSE: Creating Isolated Environment
VERBOSE: Starting the Isolated Environment

Than it seems stuck there forever, is there anyway I can look into what is happening there? It has been running for forty minutes - Shall I still wait for this?

Comment: How you package your wpf app? For example, did you use inno setup? What's the version of your windows 10?  Is it a insider preview version?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT what is inno setup? I set up the policy to bypass, the base image matching my os version. My os build version is 1607, build14393

Comment: I package the my wpf application as an exe by using install shield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shall I kill my desktop app converter process?

It seems like the application is running in isolated environment that you cannot go on. You may need to stop this progress(may be by Ctrl+C) and retry.

Firstly, please check if your application meet the requirements for converting. See [Prepare an app for conversion with the Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare). For example, check if your wpf app target version is .Net4.6.1.

Secondly, please try to use `InstallerArguments "/S/V/qn"` instead of `InstallerArguments "/S"` since `/V` pass the parameters to the inside msi from installshield.exe that can avoid pop up. And actually the best practice is that before you convert your app, try to silent install your app by command, if successfully, copy the successful installer arguments to the converter's `InstallerArguments`, it may ensure converter work well.

In additionally, with installshield packaged, you may need configure the path to your exe file after installation. Details please reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157336/desktop-app-converter-with-installshield-installer-w-discovered-exe-not-found).